# NAT x Bridge, when should I use?

Tags: wireless-networking, router

When should I use NAT mode and when Bridge?

Answer (score 0):

Setup router A as a [Wireless Bridge](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Bridge).

Then configure router B to have a subnet range that you know router A will never have. If

```
192.168.1.XXX, 192.168.0.XXX, 192.168.5.XXX
```

do not qualify then perhaps a higher number would? ie

```
192.168.150.XXX
```

Comment: by configuring the subnet you mean where, in the subnetmask field? I have updated the OP with more details.

Comment: All routers are different, but to configure the subnet with a range of 192.168.150.XXX you will generally perform the same action. In the case of dd wrt, you would modify the "Local IP address" to 192.168.150.1 and this in turn would automatically set the range for the "Start IP address". Refer to this image: http://i.imgur.com/5nJ83.png

Answer (score 0):

without going into too much explanation so I can answer your question..I will try to keep this brief (leaving out some of the details the more techy crown will obviously notice).

NAT Mode is used when you are wanting to translate one address into another.  Most Router/Firewalls work this way.  Basically it "NATs" your internal IP to your external IP.  this can be a one to one relationship or a one to many relationship (most home routers use one to many)

Bridge Mode is used when you are trying to bridge networks.  Typically (and I am assuming because of the wording of your question), it would be used when you want to "bridge" onto another network.  So you'd use it in a senerio where you would have a network port on a computer connected to a wireless bridge and that wireless bridge connects to anther wireless router and in turn the rest of the network.

SO..... Use nat mode when you want to connect multiple devices to a single connection. (like a wireless router would do) and use bridge mode when you need to connect a machine(s) to another network (like say a desktop or xbox to a wireless network when they don't have wireless adapters).

Answer (score 0):

NAT:

- When you need to share a public IP address because you don't have enough for all of your devices.
- When you need a "poor man's firewall" to guard a network from unwanted connection attempts from the Internet.

Bridge:

- Anytime else. Especially when something else is already acting as the NAT or firewall for the network.

Bridging is almost seamless and doesn't modify packets, so it really doesn't mess with anything or get in the way.

NAT rewrites packets (breaking the [End to End Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-to-end_principle)), creates separate IP address subnets (which can create hassle and confusion), and makes it hard for connections to be initiated from the "public" to the "private" side. So it gets in the way a lot. It should be avoided.